# How to disable WPF ContextMenu animations?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to hunt down what bit I need to tweak to get ContextMenus in WPF to stop animating when they appear/disappear.

From what I can tell, WPF creates a Popup to host the ContextMenu. The Popup looks at its PopupAnimation property and decides how to animate. What I want to do is always have that set to "None".

I've tried setting a global unnamed style with a TargetType of Popup that sets PopupAnimation to None but this does not work. If I break in System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.SetupAnimations I can see that the animation type is still set to Fade. I'm guessing that it hasn't had a chance to apply styles yet..

I've tried hooking ContextMenuOpening but there's no access to a Popup in there that I could find.

What else could I try?

*Note that this is sort of the second part of another question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121726/how-to-prevent-animating-menus-in-wpf). The advice there worked great for menus and everything else we had that was animating, but the one exception has been ContextMenus. They animate based on properties in code, not a template. I verified this by pulling the ContextMenu template out using the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641634/default-contextmenu-style-wpf/676176#676176).*

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've been struggling with this too. I've found that the solution is to "override" the [system parameter that control popup animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.menupopupanimationkey.aspx).

Do this by defining a resource (perhaps in your `Themes\Generic.xaml`) like this:

```
<PopupAnimation x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}">None</PopupAnimation>
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for! Woo! Happy day.

Comment: Thanks! I always had a feeling that WPF context menu were slugish compared to the system ones. Now I know it was caused by animations.

Answer (score 6):

I spent a good half hour trying to figure out how to do this in code - I'm sure its obvious if you know the framework better:

```
var app = new Application();
app.Resources.Add(SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey, PopupAnimation.None);
app.Run(myThing);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your previous question, **Rob** showed you the reason why it acts like that. Can you not create a new `ControlTemplate` for your `ContextMenu` and set `PopupAnimation` property to `None` like the following :

```
               <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" 
                   AllowsTransparency="true" 
                   Focusable="false" 
                   HorizontalOffset="-2" 
                   IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                   PopupAnimation="None" 
                   Placement="Right" 
                   VerticalOffset="-3">
```

You could create your own `ContextMenu` or apply a `ControlTemplate` using the shown code to specific instances.

Comment: As I said above, ContextMenu is different. What Rob was explaining was a binding inside of the MenuItem template that directly asked the OS for a flag whether it should animate or not. In this case, there is code in the Popup class doing the work. And while the template for a MenuItem includes the animation which is easy to disable in a template override, ContextMenu is put inside of that Popup by something inside of WPF. I need a way to access its containing Popup at construction time to kill the animation, but can't figure out where it comes from or how to alter it.